# Is setting include path and autoloading two different things?

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload, zend-autoloader

I'm noticing that adding the include path of a folder I need is not enough to access the classes.

I have a folder application/tests/ which contains application/tests/Test.php

class Test.php is named Test without any prefixes

```
class Test {

}
```

If I add the tests folder only in the include path

```
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/tests')
```

The class Test.php doesn't work in the controllers

```
new Test()
```

so isn't including the folder in the include path enough?

Comment: The autoload function from ZF map the class name to a folder/file path. Ie : a class in the folder /models/db/connection.php must be named model_db_connection (Zend automatically match models to model in the class name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@StasM has it right. But here's a little more explanation.

The `include_path` tells PHP where to look when it executes an `include`, an `include_once`, a `require`, or a `require_once`. Of course, these `include`s and `require`s always reference a particular *file*.

Autoloading is specifically about missing *classes*. When an as-yet-unloaded class is referenced in code - typically, though not exclusively, by invoking the `new` operator, as in your example - then autoloading is a process that can kick in with an algorithm for loading the class. This process typically involves starting from the name of the missing class and producing a collection of possible pathnames - either absolute in the filesystem or relative to entries in the `include_path` - from the name of the missing class and then doing performing an `include` in the hopes that the class definition resides in one of them.

In your case, you have called for a class named "Test". The file containing this class resides in the file `APPLICATION_PATH . 'tests/Test.php'`. And you have placed the directory `APPLICATION_PATH . 'tests'` in the `include_path`. But until there is an autoloading algorithm in place, there is no way for the system to connect the class name `'Test'` to the file name `'Test.php'`.

The [PEAR-style class name convention](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php) would provide this connection. And an autoloader that employs that convention - like the default Zend Framework autoloader - would be able to perform that mapping from class name to file name, and then `include` the required file.

As a final complication, the conventional Zend Framework directory layout convention places certain classes in folders that are *NOT* on the include path: models, forms, services, controllers, view helpers, action helpers, etc. That's why you will often see more configuration of the autoloader - typically in the `Bootstrap` class - defining a mapping between certain classnames and certain places in the filesystem that are *off* the `include_path`.

For example, a class named 'Default_Model_User' might - at first glance - be expected to reside on the `include_path` in a file `'Default/Model/User.php'`. But the standard app directory structure wants to place that file in 'application/models/User.php'. Note the plural *'models'* and the lowercase *'m'* in the path name, as well as the presence of "Default" in the classname. Extra config on the autoloader is required in order to make sense of that, the provide a pattern for the classname-to-filename mapping. This is usually accomplished with a [resource autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html).

Hope any of this helps, either you or someone else. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Include path shows where PHP would look for scripts that it is about to include - so that when you say `include('blah.php')` PHP engine would look for `blah.php` in all paths in the include path.

Autoloading is the functionality that allows certain function to be called when PHP detects that class is needed but not defined. In this function, you can use the include path to find the file containing the class and load it, but these are absolutely different things.

`realpath()` is not related to any of those and is a function that returns unique filesystem path of a given file, with things like `..` and symbolic links resolved.